# How can I convert a .map file to a FITS file?

Tags: python, fits, map-files

I was wondering if anyone knows how to convert .map file to .fits file, so that I can read the .fits file in Python?

Comment: Tell something more about `.map` and `.fits` format. What program use it ?

Comment: I got a some data from an IDL pipeline that produces output in the form of .map file, I want to convert this into .fits file.or is there a way to read .map files on python? and get the data out in the form of headers and values in arrays and then I know how to write it to a fits file after.

Comment: FITS is a standard file format used for a good deal of Astronomy data.  I don't know about ".map" though.  It sounds like some ad-hoc format.

Comment: For that matter the question of reading FITS files in Python is separate so I edited it out of your question.  For working with FITS files in Python you will want to look at either [astropy.io.fits](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/index.html) or [fitsio](https://github.com/esheldon/fitsio).  

Also questions looking for a specific tool are somewhat off topic for Stack Overflow.  You might be better asking on the [AstroPy mailing list](http://mail.scipy.org/mailman/listinfo/astropy)