# How to read or convert a .MAP File Extension document with python?

Tags: python, r

Is there a simple way (or a library available) to read the data in a ".map" file extension document preferably with Python (or in R)?

I am working with a modelling tool in python (PCRaster) that writes maps with the .map file extension. Interestingly however, I have not found a python library that can open and study these files.

Cheers,

[A similar question is made here, unfortunately unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24393424/how-can-i-convert-a-map-file-to-a-fits-file)

[Here a .txt file is converted to .map, but can't see how to reverse this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40877629/convert-text-file-to-plink-ped-and-map-format)

[Here is a list of uses cases from Wikipedia for the .map file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAP_(file_format))

Comment: The wikipedia link isn't a definition, it's a list of use-cases. I don't think your use case is among them (Duke Nukem map, Halo map, Quake map, etc.). I think the specification you should be looking at is the [Import and Export sections of the `pcraster` documentation](http://pcraster.geo.uu.nl/pcraster/4.1.0/doc/manual/secimport.html#creation-of-a-pcraster-map-data-import).

Answer (score 1):

So I have not yet found a way read the .map files from PCRaster and be able to plot them directly, but I did just come across the ability to convert a .map file to a Numpy Array, which can then be used to plot elsewhere.

For this, Numpy, [Aguila](http://pcraster.geo.uu.nl/pcraster/4.0.1/doc/aguila/index.html) and [PCRaster](http://pcraster.geo.uu.nl/downloads/latest-release/) need to be installed. After, the commands can be run from a python script file.

From PCRaster maps to Numpy:

```
pcr2numpy(map, mv)
```

From Numpy to PCRaster

```
numpy2pcr(dataType, array, mv)
```

The following is an example from [the PCRasterPython documentation page](http://pcraster.geo.uu.nl/pcraster/4.0.1/doc/python/pcraster/differences.html):

```
import numpy
from pcraster import *
from pcraster.numpy import *

setclone("clone.map")

a = numpy.array([[12,5,21],[9,7,3],[20,8,2],[5,6,-3]])

# conver a to a PCRaster Python map
# with the value 20 indicating a 'missing value' cell
n2p = numpy2pcr(Nominal, a, 20)
print "cellvalue:", cellvalue(n2p, 2, 3)[0]

# write it to a PCRaster map
report(n2p, "n2p.map")
# read the PCRaster map back
p2n = readmap("n2p.map")
# print it as a numpy array
# missing value is replaced by 9999
print pcr2numpy(p2n, 9999)
```

The above which prints:

```
cellvalue: 3
[[  12    5   21]
 [   9    7    3]
 [9999    8    2]
 [   5    6   -3]]
```

Comment: Based on this [documentation][1], it should be possible to develop pure python code for reading this so-called RUU Cross System Format. I have some files available with their *.bil equivalents which may also come in handy.


  [1]: http://pcraster.geo.uu.nl/download/doc/csf.pdf